# Firebase.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

[Net Ninja's React Redux & Firebase Tutorial(2018)](https://youtu.be/JA1Z0u4dr0E)

Currently working through this tutorial, and in *5:56* into his tutorial, he is in projectActions.js. The code presented is the exact replica of my code.
However I get this error:

`TypeError: firebase.collection is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
export const createProject = (project) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
        //make an async call to firebase
        const firebase = getFirestore();
        firebase.collection('projects').add({
            ...project,
            authorFirstName: 'Net',
            authorLastName: 'Ninja',
            authorID: 12345,
            createdAt: new Date(),
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_PROJECT', project});
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR', err});
        })
    }
};
```

Looked through Firebase's docs, but with no avail, so unsure how to resolve this error

Thanks for any help

**Edit 1**

As requested, my config file(data removed):

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAnalytics } from 'firebase/analytics';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


export default firebase;
```

The object that 'firestore' returns looks like this:
[image: result of 'console.log(firestore)']

Comment: Where are you intializing firebase/firestore?

Comment: The 'getFirestore' function allows the 'firebase' (variable name) to have a reference to the firebase db. '.collection('projects')' should be connecting to the 'projects' collection the firebase db.
In terms of initialising firebase/firestore, this is done in the 'fbConfig.js' file, which is then passed to 'index.js'

Comment: Can you share your config file by removing any personal data inside that? And also, can you please share your firestore structure?

Comment: I have shared the config file, however I am unsure what you mean by 'share my firebase structure'...

Comment: That means to take a screenshot of what your Firestore looks like from the console and add it to the question. It will help us understand the structure of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my own Solution

The reason why my code didnt work, was because i hadnt imported the initialised `app` into my index file. And the passed it into `getFirestore()`. Therefore there was no connection between the config and the `createProject` function.

Here is the code:

```
import app from '../../config/fbConfig.js';

export const createProject = (project) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        //make an async call to firebase
        const db = getFirestore(app).collection("projects")
            db.add({
                ...project,
                authorFirstName: 'Net',
                authorLastName: 'Ninja',
                authorID: 12345,
                createdAt: new Date(),
            }).then(() => {
                dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_PROJECT', project });
            }).catch((err) => {
                dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR', err });
            })
    }
};
```

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};
// Initialize Firebase
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// export const auth = getAuth(app);
export default app
```

This creates a new collection in the firebase db.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider including a brief explanation of [how and why this solved the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help readers to better understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have new Modular SDK (`V9.0.0+`) installed and following an old tutorial which uses older name-spaced syntax. I'd recommend following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk) and switch to newer syntax (the docs also contain examples with older syntax). Try refactoring your code to:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAnalytics } from 'firebase/analytics';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const firestore = getFirestore(app)
```

```
import { firestore } from '../path/to/config/file';
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

export const createProject = (project) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore}) => {
    //make an async call to firebase
    
    addDoc(collection(db, "projects"), {
      ...projectData
    }).then(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_PROJECT', project});
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR', err});
    })
  }
};
```

Comment: I have tried your method, however there are a few problems..
First, there was not a default export for 'fbConfig.js'
Second, there is import error: 'firestore' is not exported from '../../config/fbConfig.js'.
Third, db in the collection function is not defined.